# Unity Player Won't Jump Sometimes

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am following [this tutorial](https://youtu.be/gB1F9G0JXOo) for reference, particularly at 4:03:34.

My issue is that my player wont jump sometimes when I hit the space bar. It seems to be working just fine for the dude in the tutorial, but its not working for me. Here is the code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEditor.Profiling.Memory.Experimental;
using UnityEngine;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private float moveForce = 10f;
    [SerializeField]
    private float jumpForce = 11f;
    private float movementX;

    [SerializeField]
    private Rigidbody2D myBody;
    private SpriteRenderer sr;
    private Animator anim;
    private string walk_Animation = "Walk";

    private bool isGrounded = true;
    private string Ground_Tag = "Ground";

    private void Awake()
    {
        myBody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
        sr = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
    }

    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    void Update()
    {
        PlayerMoveKeyboard();
        AnimatePlayer();
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        PlayerJump();
    }

    void PlayerMoveKeyboard()
    {
        movementX = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        transform.position += new Vector3(movementX, 0f, 0f) * Time.deltaTime * moveForce;
    }

    void AnimatePlayer()
    {
        if (movementX > 0)
        {
            anim.SetBool(walk_Animation, true);
            sr.flipX = false;
        }
        else if (movementX < 0)
        {
            anim.SetBool(walk_Animation, true);
            sr.flipX = true;
        }
        else
        {
            anim.SetBool(walk_Animation, false);
        }
    }

    void PlayerJump()
    {
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && isGrounded)
        {
            Debug.Log("Jump");
            myBody.AddForce(new Vector2(0f, jumpForce), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
            isGrounded = false;
        }
    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag(Ground_Tag))
        {
            isGrounded = true;
        }
    }
}
```

I spam the `Space` key, and every once in a while my player jumps and get the "Jump" print on my console.

I have seen some videos on Youtube that address this issue for 3D games, but I get really confused when I try to apply it to my 2D project. Keep in mind, I am still quite the beginner, so it may seem obvious to you, but not to me :,)

I tried removing the `isGrounded` variable to see if that was causing the issue, but the same problem still occurs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Player Inputs should be always in the Update method since it's called every frame.

Why the Jump input sometimes doesn't register sometimes because FixedUpdate it's not always been invoked, since it depends on physics calculation and not per frame.

You can easily fix the bug by moving the PlayerJump from FixedUpdate to Update.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yup. That worked perfectly. Thank you! Though I am curious why it seemed to work in the tutorial.

Comment: I believe it's not working for him sometimes as well and he didn't recognize the issue (just speculating). However, it's undeniably wrong putting Inputs on FixedUpdate.

You can learn more about the difference between Update and FixedUpdate here: https://blog.logrocket.com/update-vs-fixedupdate-vs-lateupdate-in-unity/#:~:text=For%20one%2C%20there%20is%20an,Update%20functions%20have%20been%20called.